# While loop creates fatal runtime error when input is bigger than 10

Tags: c, while-loop, fatal-error

First of all i apologize if the title of  this thread is not specific enough, but I couldn't think of any way to make the title more specific.

Second of all, let me explain what the problem is. 
I am currently trying to figure out how to create a loop that will run as many times as it needs, until the value that it creates is equal or higher to a number given by the user. I know that this sounds weird, but let me try and make it clearer. My program simulates a die roll, which means that the outcomes are random ( or pseudo random, but it's irrelevant to this problem ). The loop that I am trying to make has to roll the die until the added together random numbers will be equal to or higher than the user input. So, let's say that the user wants 55 to be the input. The loop has to run however many times, until the sum of the outcomes is 55 or higher. Hopefully that is clear enough explanation of the criteria.

```
while (turnscore <= input)
roll = (rand() % 6 + 1);
turnscore = turnscore + roll;
printf("You Rolled : %d\n", roll);
turnscore + turnscore;
```

The above is my loop that creates the fatal runtime error. I used the while loop, because I thought that for this problem it will be the right one. I might be wrong.
Also, when I change the logical operators in the first line from (turnscore <= input) to (turnscore >= input) my program shows nothing except for : "You rolled 0".

Any clues, hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

---

All right guys, I really appreciate the help, but I don't think I have explained my problem well enough, and therefore we are not on the same page. Let me try to explain the problem or the purpose of the program again, so that you understand what my problem is.

First of all, the program is supposed to be a die roll simulator. There can be two different criteria as to how the program goes. First one is : If the input number is less than 10, roll the die X times, where X is the input number. This part, I have already solved, and it is working fine.

The second criteria is : If the input number is 10 or more, roll the die until the score in the turn is equal or higher than the input number. This part I have a problem with, because what I did is changed my for loop to while loop (and I did it wrong) with some changes to the syntax but it crashes the program and the debugger shows : " fatal runtime error".

Hopefully, this will clear the misunderstanding between us. : )

Comment: Where is "roll" declared? Are you sure it is of the correct type? Also, did you mean to use brackets with your while loop? And did you mean to assign "turnscore + turnscore" to anything?

Comment: What line does the error happen on? What did the debugger say?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Looks like you have pretty much answered the question.

Comment: Roll is declared as a global function at the beginning of the program, I didn't post the whole thing up, because I thought there is no reason to as this loop is the only thing that creates the problem. I can post it up if you want me to, that s not a problem. I'm not sure if I understand your question about the brackets, but I have put them there, since I was following the syntax of the while loop. I used "turnscore + turnscore" to update the value of turnscore, so that the criteria can be met eventually.

Comment: The debugger doesn't say which line the error happens at, all it shows is " Fatal Runtime Error"

Comment: Note that `turnscore + turnscore;` does nothing, and isn't part of the loop.  Maybe you had in mind `turnscore += roll;`?  And you really need some braces around the code after the `while`?

Comment: I see what the problem is -> you forgot to roll your die located next to your computer to compute the probability of getting something greater than 10 in your program. Remember to always keep your die close at hand near your desk.

Comment: @Kozmik, the purpose of the program isnt to roll anything greater than 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code makes no sense to me. This is in an infinite loop:

```
while (turnscore <= input)
roll = (rand() % 6 + 1);
```

Given your requirements, the code should look like this:

```
int roll = 0;
int turnscore = 0;

while (turnscore <= input) {
    roll = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    printf("You rolled %d\n", roll)
    turnscore += roll;
}

printf("Total : %d\n", turnscore);
```

Comment: My apologies if the code/explanation makes no sense. Let me try again. The roll variable is a random number generator / die roll simulation. The number of times the die is rolled is dependent on the input. The turnscore is a sum of all the outcomes of die rolls.

Comment: @Muffik9 Maybe `while(input--)` would make more sense.

Comment: My answer does exactly that: it roll the dice however many times until the sum is bigger than `input`. And you don't need to have a `turnscore` variable either.

Comment: Thank you Zoff Dino, your answer solved the problem. I didn't notice it before, because I got confused as to what the output was, but now I understand it. Sorry that it didn't occur to me straight away. I have got one more question though. The output shows the sum of the rolls, is there any way to make it show what numbers were rolled as well ?

Comment: Thank you Zoff Dino, you have been really helpfull and I think I understand while loops better now. Sorry if my explanation of the problem wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

Your `while` loop isn't followed by curly braces, so it only applies to the statement that immediately follows it.  Since `turnscore` isn't changed in that statement, you end up with an infinite loop if `input` is greater than 6.

With proper indentation, this is what your code looks like:

```
while (turnscore <= input)
    roll = (rand() % 6 + 1);
turnscore = turnscore + roll;
printf("You Rolled : %d\n", roll);
turnscore + turnscore;
```

Also, `turnscore + turnscore` has no net effect.  You're adding two values together, but they aren't being assigned to anything.

What you probably want it this:

```
turnscore = 0;
while (turnscore <= input) {
    roll = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    printf("You Rolled : %d\n", roll);
    turnscore = turnscore + roll;
}
printf("Turn score: %d\n", turnscore);
```

The curly braces now in place allow the `while` loop to iterate over multiple statements instead of just one.

Comment: The changes that you have suggested, which I am grateful for, have fixed the program to some extent. By that I mean that the program doesn't crash anymore, but the output is : " You rolled : " and then the random number from the number generator. This isn't quite the solution to my problem, but it gives me something to work on, so thank you for that : )

Comment: @Muffik9 I edited the code above to print each roll inside of the loop and the score outside of the loop.

Comment: Than you very much. Now the loop does exactly what it is supposed to and how it is supposed to. Thank you once again, you have been very helpful : )